# Issue with sum of probabilities of probability distribution function of a geometric random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Is it possible that the sum of probabilities of geometric distribution for "$k = 1,...,n$", where k is number of trials until the first success, is not equal to 1?

I'm asking this, because I encounter a problem, when writing a program in a language, like Matlab, it's Scilab, and I observe that for probability $p = 0.6$, and $n = 10$ I do not get the sum of probabilities equal to $1$ (but very close to 1). Also, I noticed that the first value for cumulative distribution function is $0.6$, while using Matlab function `cdfgeo`, the first value is $0.84$, which gives the right result. So, is it possible that the sum of probabilities be not $1$?

As additional information, I use the formula: $$P_{X}(x) = (1-p)^{k-1}p$$
where $X$ is a geometric random variable, $p = \text{probability}$, and $k = \text{number of trials}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $k$ can take on any positive integer value; it is not limited just up to $10$.

Comment: Yes, I understand, so it's normal that for n = 10  I get something like this ?

Comment: Yes.  If you go up to $10$ and then stop, your probabilities would add up to somewhat less than $1$.

Comment: So, then it's really so, thank you.